# How to use downloaded moderncv template with MiKTeX?

Tags: templates, moderncv

I have downloaded a template named `moderncv` but don't know how to use it.

As I am a beginner, please suggest me the pdf's describing the solution.

Comment: So what you have is some `.tex` file of an example `moderncv` class?  Or are you adding the `moderncv` class to you distro?

Comment: possibly related to [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063)

Comment: How much experience do you have with LaTeX? Are you trying to use LaTeX because you want your resume to match the pdf output of the template you found, or do you have prior experience with LaTeX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `moderncv`is still missing, but you will find some examples (look on [`CTAN`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples)) showing the usage (`.tex` files) and the results (`.pdf` files).

You can also search this side for the tag `moderncv` to find related questions to class `moderncv`that should help you.

The examples and this side should allow you to build your own cv.

If you have problems to install the class for your distribution follow the given link in the comment of @henrique.

To check if you have `moderncv` installed on your system try to compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}    
\moderncvcolor{green}  
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                           % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                          % optional
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                           % optional
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                             % optional
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}              % optional
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty

\end{document}
```