# Font \fntlogosmsl=logosl8 scaled 600 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, logos

I just bought a new computer. So I instal Miktek and Texmaker on it and wanted to change something on my resume. Unfortunately I have the following errors :

[image]
[image]

I searched for solution but nothing worked.

p.s. it works perfectly on my old computer

A minimal example producing the error is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{texlogos}

\begin{document}
Test. 
\end{document}
```

The same error occurs on texlive 2015.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you provide more details of your document?  One guess would be that you are using `moderncv`.  In which case you should make sure that Miktex has installed all necessary dependencies for this package.

Comment: Yes, I'm using moderncv. I redownload the moderncv package and add manually all the files in  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\moderncv but nothing change. The code in  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128415/how-to-use-downloaded-moderncv-template-with-miktex work fine.

Comment: You say the other code works fine.  Then you should show us your code, or prefarably a cut down [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so we can help work out what the problem is.  By the way, have you tried installing moderncv via miktex's package manager system?  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473/15925 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/15925.  Fonts don't reside in the style directory.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with a standard `article` document containing just the `texlogos` package.  The strange thing is `logo8` loads fine but `logosl8` does not.  Both are on my system and the `.pfb` files can be found via `kpsewhich`.  We need a font expert.  Or you could try the CTAN list.

Comment: You have to install the `mflogo` MiKTeX package: http://miktex.org/packages/mflogo. Launch the wizard for MiKTeX and install the package (in Administrator mode, if you so installed MiKTeX).

Comment: @egreg I get the same error on texlive 2015 despite the package being installed - see my comments and the minimal example I have added to the question.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Indeed! Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

The “Logo” fonts distribution underwent a restructuring between TeX Live 2013 and 2014 and the same happened to MiKTeX.

The Metafont sources that are listed in CTAN under `<CTAN>/fonts/mflogo/mf` were almost all copies of those in `<CTAN>/sys­tems/knuth/dist/lib/` and are now packaged in TeX Live as `knuth-lib`.

Unfortunately, *one* of the font sources is missing and it is `logosl8.mf` (for which another package provides the PFB version). The contents of the file is very short

```
% 8-point slanted METAFONT logo
% [ heavily borrowed from D. E. Knuth ]

% Copyright (C) 1995--1999 Ulrik Vieth
%
% This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
% modify it under the terms of the LaTeX Project Public License
% as described in lppl.txt in the base LaTeX distribution; either
% version 1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

slant := 1/4;
input logo8
```

A bug report should be filed to the TeX Live maintainers (MiKTeX should follow) so they do something about the problem. In the meantime, having a `logosl8.mf` in the working directory should suffice to get out of the dilemma.

On the other hand, I'd be wary of loading `texlogos`, which is undocumented and wrongly written as it uses `\font` directly.

### Update

As of October 15, 2015, the distribution of the logo fonts has been updated and the hack of keeping `logosl8.mf` along with the file is not needed any more (on TeX Live 2015 and later).

Comment: I'm sorry but I placed the logosl8.mf in the working directory but nothing changed for me.